# How we can update ci_session as SECURE flags in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

ci_session  also needs SECURE flags. Is this possible in codeigniter ?

Any help regrading this . Please update.

Comment: And one more thing  how we 'll remove expiration date from csrf_cookie ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Sessions will apply certain cookie related variables found in `application/config/config.php` which includes `$config['cookie_secure']`. Setting this to `TRUE` will set the SECURE flag on session cookies.

CSRF cookies will use `$config['sess_expiration']` which if set to 0 (zero) means the cookies will remain set until the browser is closed.